How to properly override bpy.ops.node.backimage_fit()?
I need some help calling bpy.ops.node.backimage_fit(), I cannot find the proper context override
screen = bpy.context.screen
for area in screen.areas:
    if area.type == "NODE_EDITOR":
        windows = context.window_manager.windows
        print(context.active_node) # Node Editor area not found!?

        with context.temp_override(
            active_node= composite_node,
            window=windows[-1], # new opened window
            area=area, # node editor
            region=area.regions[3], # bl_rna: <bpy_struct, Struct("SpaceNodeEditor") at 0x00007FF61BDE9C80>
            space_data=area.spaces[0] # <bpy_struct, SpaceNodeEditor at 0x0000019FBA1E6388>,
        ):
            bpy.ops.node.backimage_fit()

Attached is a picture of the new window I'm calling this on (it's a different window from the "main" window)
This seems to be the C code that defines the poll for the operator, but I don't think I understand it
https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/ad7d7212c10f87ce153f0270c5c26b2317375b1c/source/blender/editors/space_node/node_view.cc#L58

I tried to brute-force it but still isn't working
  for window in context.window_manager.windows:
      screen = window.screen
      for area in screen.areas:
          for region in area.regions:
              try:
                  with context.temp_override(
                      active_node=composite_node,
                      window=window,
                      area=area,
                      region=region,
                  ):
                      bpy.ops.node.backimage_fit()
              except:
                  print(window, screen, area, region)

